# Spectral Invariants

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

Peter Walters An Introduction to Ergodic Theory Chapter 2 Page 66 
What does the idea (Property P) mean ? 
I couldn't understand it [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not referring to any specific property at all.

Rather, a property is said to be isomorphism invariant if, whenever $T_1$ has the property and $T_2$ is isomorphic to $T_1$, then $T_2$ has the property too.

The same goes for conjugacy invariant and spectral invariant.